# Fix Japanese IME after April 2018 update

Tags: windows-10, ime, japanese, windows-10-v1803

I have this problem on two computers now.  I had the Japanese language pack installed, and used the IME keyboard.  I used to be able to use CTRL-CAPSLOCK to switch to Hiragana after changing the language to Japanese.  I could also right click the A icon in the system tray and pick Hiragana from the menu.  This allowed me to type romaji which were changes to the appropriate hirgana/kanji.  But after installing the April 2018 update 1803, both methods don't change from half-width alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be related to the custom dictionary file (imjp15cu) as it gives an error whenever "edit" under custom dictionary is clicked in the advanced settings.

From a non-1803 system, copy the files in C:\Windows\IME\IMEJP\DICTS to the same location on the affect 1803 machine and reboot.

Comment: SUCCESS!  it is definitely related to the dictionary files.

Comment: I copied the C:\Windows\IME\IMEJP\DICTS from a non 1803 machine and it resolved the issue entirely.

Comment: Might want to edit that into your answer then, otherwise your answer is just a comment :-)

Comment: I did in a different way. 'Open advanced settings', in 'Dictionary/Auto-tuning' tab, click Repair dictionaries button. I just worked afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

There were computers running Win10 1803 with the Japanese language pack installed that are not affected by this problem.  I have copied the %systemroot%\%windir%\IME\IMJP\DICTS (all files were dated 4/10 or 11/2018) from one of those computers; overwriting the currently installed DICTS.  Restart the computer and all worked for me.  The non-1803(1709) version of the DICTS didn't worked at all.

Comment: November 2018 is in approximately 5 months.  This answer is confusing.  1803 was released on April 30th so a file with a modified date of May 10th doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @ramhound I wouldn't assume the timestamps for individual files are necessarily accurate.

Comment: @Andy - Which is the reason this answer is confusing.  The author could clarify their answer, although even with a clarification, it does not really answer the author's question.

Comment: @Ramhound If the answer is correctly saying what the timestamps of the files actually are, then I don't see how its confusing.